# creating a multinode cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm using Cassandra and trying to create a multi node cluster at first time.
The problem is that one node is up with private IP (i.e. 192.168.50.3) and the other node with the loop back IP.

I have changed on both of them the:

> ```
> cassandra.yaml file those Parameters:
> listen_address = local machine address
> rpc_address =  local machine address
> listen_interface = eth0
> rpc_interface = eth0
> seeds = other machine address.
> ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: don't set both listen_address and listen_interface. You should comment one of them out. The [2.1 docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html) say "Set this parameter [listen_address] or listen_interface, but not both."

Answer (score 0):

All the nodes in the cluster should have the same seeds.

So pick one node ip (or two) and set it to all node seeds.

Comment: hi it doesn't change the behavior because even if I run only one of them it keeps running in loopback ip. so currently I just run 'Cassandra' with no parameters & all ip's are at yaml file